# Identify entire empty rows and ignore rows that only have some empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A            B             C              D
1      Product       Sale         Costs          Profit
2     Product A      50                            50  
3     Product B      60                            60
4
5     Product C      20
6     Product D      80            70               10
7
8     
9     Product E      40            15               25
10
11
12    Product F     120            85               35
13    Product G     140                            140
14    Product H                    50              -50
```

As you can see there are empty cells in between the numbers.
Now I want to identify all rows that are **completely** empty.
In this case that would be **Row 4, 7, 8, 10, 11**.

So I tried to go with

```
Select A1:D14 --> Tab: Start --> Menu: Find & Select --> Go to Special --> Blanks
```

After this procedure all empty cells are selected *(for example also Cell C2, C3, C5, D5, etc.)* However, I want that only the completely empty rows are selected. If there is a single cell with a content in the row the row should be ignored.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If I put a filter in the first row in Column A the only options I have in the filter are "Product A" and "Product B".

Comment: Ah now I see. Did not know that there is a difference. I always just put the filter in the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The COUNTA function counts the number of cells that are not empty in a
>   range.
>   https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509

If you're ok with an extra column you could use the formula:
`=COUNTA($A2:$C2)` and drag down.

You can then filter that column for 0's.

To select the cells you can then use the same method as you originally tried, but select *Visible cells only* rather than *Blanks*.

Or as @pnuts commented - just filter column A, as a blank in there appears to indicate the whole row is blank.

**Edit:**  *Added after answer accepted.*
To show how it selects just the blank rows:

Select your data, not including the headers:
[image]

Filter column A to show just the blanks.  At this stage the whole table is selected, including the hidden rows:
[image]

Using *Find & Select* > *Go To Special* > *Visible Cells Only*:
[image]

Remove the filter to show all values with just the blank rows selected:
[image]

Comment: I'll add clarification to the answer - and add that it was edited in after acceptance.

Comment: lol, didn't think it would be for your benefit.  Kinda guessed you know what you're doing with 1000+ score & posts on formula questions. :)

Comment: Ah ok. He didn't mention delete, just selecting them. :p  I think plagiarising is part of the job these days - the important bit is whether the coder understands what they've just copied.

Comment: Desperately trying to find some coder logic humour cartoon... best I can find at short notice:  https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/d-coding/archive/2015/10/31/developer-humor-coding-logic.aspx